# Check pkg content in Solaris 10

Tags: solaris

I using solaris 10 and i have a pkg files how can i list out the its contents?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list of the (to be installed) files can be displayed using the pkgchk command:

```
pkgchk -d package.pkg -l
```

If the pkg file has contains more than one package, you will be prompted. e.g.

```
The following packages are available:
  1  JetRedHat     JET RedHat support
                   (sparc) 4.4
  2  SUNWjet       Sun JumpStart Enterprise Toolkit
                   (sparc,i386) 4.7

Select package(s) you wish to process (or 'all' to process
```

The pkgtrans command can change the entire package from datastream to file system fomat 
if the -i option is not used. This can be helpful if you want to see the actions
 that occur after the package is installed onto a system.
e.g:

```
less SUNWjet/install/postinstall
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Solaris package management system doesn't make this easy.  You could try the following:

```
pkgtrans -i <pkgfile> spool
```

This will extract the pkginfo and pkgmap (list of files) files to /var/spool/pkg/package_name.  You could review them there.

Answer (score 0):

I get the package content through the command below:

```
$ strings <your-package-name> | grep ^"1 "
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run  for a spesific  package which  installed;

```
#pkgchk  -l <packagename>
```

Also  before  installing you can run and check  package content.

```
pkgchk -d  expect-5.45-sol10-x86-local   -l
```

And you can check  for a spesific  path.

```
pkgchk -lp /usr/local/bin/expect
```

Check  this  [link](http://casesup.com/knowledgebase/how-to-check-package-content-solaris-10/)  for  more details and  command  usage examples.